# What type of plumbing fitting is this? (Fridge)

Tags: plumbing, refrigerator, ice-maker

This picture is the fitting that comes off the back of my fridge for water into the fridge. Fridge manual says it is 1/4" but doesn't mention fitting type. Is it compression?

And if it is compression, then this fitting should work to connect to a 6 ft hose to ice maker outlet box which are both 1/4" compression fittings?

[Connection Fitting](https://smile.amazon.com/Carter-Maker-Water-Compression-Fitting/dp/B07SVPVLKC)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's a (cheesy plastic) compression fitting. Depending on the hose (often male to male, rather than male to female) you might need a female-female coupler to connect (male threads = female compression fitting - female threads = male compression fitting)

The item you have linked is both the female-female coupler and the male ends to go on hose that does not have a fitting on it already. So you may only need the center part of it, if your hoses already have fittings on them.

Answer (score 1):

It is GE refrigerator water connection tubing.

It's sort of built like compression tubing, but since it's not going to be under much pressure, they integrated in the brass compression collar into the plastic tube and molded the tip for a better fit.

https://www.zoro.com/ge-refrigerator-water-conn-tubing-15-ft-wx08x10015/i/G6150737/

Comment: If it's not this, it is very close.  I'd attribute the bell shape on yours (and the conical shape on new ones) to the tightening, age, and changes in manufacture.